# How can we say that by using pigeon hole principle , increasing and decreasing sequence length is same while proving Erdős–Szekeres theorem?

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

I was trying to prove the Erdős–Szekeres theorem using pigeon hole. The book I'm referring to, is using Proof by contradiction and then pigeon hole principle.
here's the statement

**Theorem**

```
Every sequence of n^2 + 1 distinct real numbers contains a subsequence
of length n + 1 that is either strictly increasing, or strictly decreasing
```

**Proof**

```
Let a1, a2, . . . , an^2+1 be the distinct numbers in the sequence. With term ak
associate the pair (ik, dk) where ik is the length of the longest increasing subsequence
starting at ak, and dk is the length of the longest decreasing sequence starting at
ak.
ASSUME there are no decreasing or increasing subsequences of length n+ 1 (we
give a proof by contradiction). Then ik and dk are both positive integers ≤ n, for
k = 1, 2, . . . , n^2 + 1. So there are (by the Product Rule) n
2 possible ordered pairs
(ik, dk). **By the Pigeonhole Principle, two of these pairs must be equal**

That is, for some as and at with s < t we have is = it and ds = dt.
If as < at, then since is = it, an increasing subsequence of length it + 1 can be built starting at as and following it with the increasing subsequence of length it which begins at at. Therefore is = it + 1 6= it, a CONTRADICTION.

If ax > at, we can similarly conclude that ds = dt+1+dt, a CONTRADICTION.
```

My confusion is **By the Pigeonhole Principle, two of these pairs must be equal**, how can we say both increasing and decreasing sequence length is same using Pigeon hole principle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is recognize the holes and the pigeons.

You have $n^2+1$ pigeons that corresponds to the ordered pairs $\{(i_1,k_1),(i_2,k_2), \dots, (i_{n^2+1},k_{n^2+1})\}$, such that $i_k,d_k \leq n$.

You are putting those $n^2+1$ pigeons in $n^2$ holes which are the total number of ordered pairs such that $i_k, d_k \leq n$.

Thus, there is at least one hole that has two pigeons i.e, two pairs must be equal.

Comment: Thank you!. I was interpreting it as all pairs will have same increasing and decreasing sequence length like (k1,k1) for a1 etc.., this cleared up what i was thinking wrong.